# how to deploy a exe file or desktop application online

Tags: matlab, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, cloud

the exe file was generated from matlab. I am trying a way to access the application online or run in my mobile phone(android).
Ok

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow. Please read this link so that you can create good questions that can be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MCR can not be installed on android systems, which means you can not use the Matlab Compiler to create android applications.

You surely can deploy web applications, which is [well documented](https://mathworks.com/help/compiler/webapps/create-and-deploy-a-web-app.html). Most notable is this warning from the documentation:

> Warning
>   The development version of MATLAB® Web App Server™ must be installed in a trusted intranet environment on dedicated hardware. The only purpose of the physical or virtual machine where the server is installed must be to host web apps that connect to the server. The server must never be exposed to the open Internet. For more information, see [MATLAB Web App Server Security](https://mathworks.com/help/compiler/webapps/matlab-web-app-server-security.html). [source](https://mathworks.com/help/compiler/webapps/install-matlab-web-app-server.html)